# Flask admin add computable field

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I want to show in flask admin a column with computable field (computed by python code).

I have found next way how to do it:

Add computable `@property` to the model then add this property to admin.

Is there a way to do same without changing the model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare any number of column fields that are not part of the model and then specify a column formatter to provide the data for these columns, example:

```
class TestView(ModelView):

    # 'computed' is not in out model
    column_list = ('name', 'subject', 'sent', 'recipients', 'computed')

    def _computed_formatter(view, context, model, name):
        # `view` is current administrative view
        # `context` is instance of jinja2.runtime.Context
        # `model` is model instance
        # `name` is property name
        return "Hello World"

    column_formatters = {
        'computed': _computed_formatter,
    }
```

Comment: From https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/ it seems that formaters executed with jinja context. Is it ok to access db and calculate some data based on raws from other table that linked with current model instance ?

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander Yes

Comment: pylint have problem with `def _computed_formatter` without `self` in args and with add of @stathicmethod it don't work so i mowed call out of the class